# Items Box with limit of objects in row (Large icons view style in Windows Explorer)

Tags: wpf, xaml

Can't find a solution to a pretty simple UI problem:
I have a model with a Images property. The Images property holds a collection of items Image.
As for now on - I have a ListBox and binding a ListBoxItem data template to Images.Image and all good. But I have each item on a new line. Not good.
What I am willing to achieve is, lets describe as, a Listbox with Horizontal items orientation and limit of items in a row. Just like Large icons view style in Windows Explorer.
Have somebody previously implemented such a solution? Any advice will be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `WrapPanel` (or some other appropriate Panel) as the ListBox's `ItemsPanel`, and disable horizontal scrolling:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" Width="100" Margin="5"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `ListBox`'s `ItemPanelTemplate` to `WrapPanel`, like [this](https://wpf.2000things.com/2011/10/04/400-using-a-wrappanel-as-the-items-panel-for-a-listbox/).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it is always like that - but as soon as I asked, I have found an alternative solution with usage of ListView:

```
           <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: This works exactly the same with a ListBox. You just don't have to disable horizontal scrolling because you use a different Panel.

Comment: Agree, but I posted alternative solution, because, well, they suit different situation. With wrapper - the items will move on next row, depending of the fact if there is place for the "last item" (correct me if am am wrong). In my approach I am setting - how many items I want to see on a single row, with UniformGrid.

Comment: Sure, that's the reason why you can set the ItemsPanel in an ItemsControl. That is exactly what I was referring to in my answer with "WrapPanel (or some other appropriate Panel)".

Comment: All true - thank you for explanation and help. Cheers.